# Powershell prevent recursive lookup of parent folder only search child folders

Tags: file, powershell, dir, directory-listing

I have created a script which can find all files in a provided directory of a specified format. The script will recursivly search the folder structure for these files.

```
    Write-host "Please enter source Dir:"
$soureDir = read-host

Write-Host "Format to look for with .  :"
$format = read-host

#Write-host "Please enter output Dir:"
#$outDir = read-host

$Dir = get-childitem "$sourceDir" -recurse 

$files = $Dir | where {$_.extension -eq "$format"} 
$files | format-table name
```

The problem is that if i provide the path C:\scripts\files as my root search directory the script still searches through C:\scripts as well as C:\scripts\files\ which is all I wish the script to do!

This is obviously a simple fix but I am unsure what I have coded wrong.

Thanks in advance,
Craig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in the variable name you're listing: $soureDir vs $sourceDir

Try this:

```
get-childitem $sourceDir -Filter $format -recurse | format-table name
```

Comment: spelling mistake!! cant beleive it!!

Comment: Shay, I fixed the typo in your typo answer.  :)

Comment: Explanation being that `gci $nonexistantVariable` is `gci .`